# distinguishing string based on space between them

Tags: java, string

I have a text file generated by the application that contains strings like this:

```
26    
50 597 424 561
499 849
283 76
115 81
4
26

public void listingCoord() throws IOException{

    File f = new File("coord.txt");
    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(f);

    for(String s: interationList){

    writer.write(s+"\n");
    }
    writer.close();

    }

public void replay(){

    BufferedReader br = null;
    try{
        String line;
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("coord.txt"));
        while((line = br.readLine())!=null){
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    }
        catch (IOException io){ io.printStackTrace();}
    try {
        br.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

the code which listing the string is above.
simply there is a list which contains the strings as displayed, and the list and replay methods write and read the lines.

What I want to do is reading this integers, but in a different way.
I know how to read the text file and display it, but what I want is make a decision about the numbers so:

- if it is in one position without spaces like 26 send it to the right method as argument - as I have ready methods-.
- if it is in two positions with one space like 499 849 send it the right method.

and so on,

Is there a way to do this? I mean distinguishing between the number partitions based on the space they have between.

Comment: Please post the text as code, so that we can understand what you mean with space.

Comment: What are you doing in methods handling `x` `x y` `x y z`? If the same thing then wouldn't one method accepting array of elements be better?

Comment: @Pshemo methods are in three different forms: like this public void mth1(int code)  this accepting the 26 only for example. the second method mth2( int x, int y) this accepting the 283 76 for example. the third is public void mth3(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) which accepting 50 597 424 561 so each number will be placed in one int. so it will be like public void meth3(50, 597, 424, 561) . hope this one is clear ..

Comment: I was more interested in why do you need separate `foo(int)` `foo(int, int)` `foo(int, int, int)` methods instead of one `foo(int[])` or `foo(int...)`-varargs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand well, you have to know how many numbers are in line.
So you should read the text file line-by-line, and then parse Integers:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
public class Parser{
    public static void main(String[] args){ //excepiton catching needed
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File(args[0])); //for example
        while(sc.hasNextLine()){
            String line = sc.nextLine();
            String[] array = line.split(" ");
            switch(array.length){
                case 1: oneParamMethod(array[0]); break;
                case 2: twoParamMethod(array[0],array[1]); break;
                default: System.out.println("Strange line");
            }
        }
        sc.close();
    }
    public static void oneParamMethod(String param){
        int value = Integer.parseInt(param);
        // there will be your code
    }
    public static void twoParamMethod(String param1,String param2){
        int value1 = Integer.parseInt(param1);
        int value2 = Integer.parseInt(param2);
        // there will be your code
    }
}
```

Not tested
There should be used array instead of switch if possible as @Pshemo noticed at his comment

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29875780/3644902) answer, I would prefer this:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Parser {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc;
        try {
            sc = new Scanner(new File(args[0]));
            parseLines(sc);
            sc.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static void parseLines(Scanner sc) {
        while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = sc.nextLine();
            String[] array = line.split(" ");
            try {
                parseLineArray(array);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private static void parseLineArray(String[] array) throws Exception {
        switch (array.length) {
        case 0:
            throw new Exception("Empty line found");
        case 1:
        case 2:
            processEntry(array);
            break;
        default:
            throw new Exception("Too many entries: [" + array.toString() + "]");
        }
    }

    private static void processEntry(String[] array) {
        if (array.length == 1) {
            oneParamMethod(Integer.parseInt(array[0]));
        } else {
            twoParamMethod(Integer.parseInt(array[0]), Integer.parseInt(array[1]));
        }
        // your code
    }

    private static void oneParamMethod(Integer value1) {

        // your code
    }

    private static void twoParamMethod(Integer value1, Integer value2) {

        // your code
    }
}
```

- Exception Handling
- More methods, but less code in the methods, therefore more readable code
- Import nothing that you do not need (eg.: `import java.io.*`;)

Comment: I agree with your improvements, btw. I know how to handle exception, but I wanted to show the main part of the solution :-) (+1)